# limite de palavras com jquery

Tags: jquery, html-tags, input

eu estou usando o plugin jquery.tagsinput do xoxco para inserir um campo com tags no meu artigo, porem eu preciso de um limite de tags inseridas la, entao preciso de um contador de palavras para limitar quantas palavras sao inseridas, com o pluguin , sempre que o usuario digita "espaço" cria uma tag

alguem conhece algum script para isso?

ou outro plugin melhor para criar tags?

[editado]

função para contar as tags digitadas com o plugin jquery.tagsinput.js

`var tagcount = 0;
$("#tags").tagsInput({
    'width':'100%',
     onAddTag: function(elem, elem_tags){
            tagcount += $(this).length;
            if(tagcount > 10){
                $(this).removeTag(elem);
            }
        },
        onRemoveTag: function(){
            tagcount -= $(this).length;
        }
 });`

obrigado pessoal

Comment: Com os *callbacks* `onAddTag` e `onRemoveTag` você não consegue fazer isso?

Comment: @RafaelMafra vlw cara, eu dei uma pesquisada e no proprio repositorio do xoxco tem uma função para isso, obrigado cara